# Using Handlebar with D3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js, handlebars.js

I have a Handlebar template i want to include a svg graph generated from d3 into that template.Graph should be inside the template

D3 Graph

```
var dataset = [1200,3000,3200];
// dataset will change dynamically.

<script type="text/javascript">

    var w = 154;
    var h = 42;
    var rect_1_h = 5;
    var rect_2_h = rect_1_h * 2;
    var rect_2_w = rect_1_h/2;
    var rect_1_color = "#A1C9D9";
    var rect_2_color = "#999999";
    var text_color = "#555555";
    var font_size = 18;
    var font_family = "Segoe UI"

    var dataset = [1200,3000,3200];

    /*------controller----*/

    var xScale = d3.scale.linear().domain([dataset[0],dataset[2]])
    .range([0,w]);

    var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg").attr("width",w).attr("height",h);
    var rect1 = svg.append("rect").attr("x",0).attr("y",3*h/4).attr("width",w).attr("height",rect_1_h)
    .style("fill",rect_1_color);
    var rect2 = svg.append("rect").attr("x",xScale(dataset[1])).attr("y",3*h/4-rect_1_h/2).attr("width",rect_2_w)
    .attr("height",rect_2_h).style("fill",rect_2_color);

    //var texts = svg.selectAll("text").data(dataset).enter().append("text").text(function(d){ return d; }).attr("fill","red").attr("x",function(d,i){ return i*50  }).attr("y",30)

    var text1 = svg.append("text").attr("x",2).attr("y",h/3+2).text(dataset[0]).style("fill",text_color)
    .attr("font-size",font_size).attr("font-family",font_family);
    var text2 = svg.append("text").attr("x",w-42).attr("y",h/3+2).text(dataset[2]).style("fill",text_color)
    .attr("font-size",font_size).attr("font-family",font_family);
</script>
```

Handlebar template

```
<script id="datatemplate" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
      {{#each objects}}
      <tr>
      <td>{{lp}}<span class="text1">{{lp2}}</span></td>
      <td>{{dc}}<span class="text1">{{dc2}}</span></td>
      <td>{{lp}}<span class="text1">{{lp2}}</span></td>
      </tr>
      {{/each}} 
</script>
```

Comment: You probably should read this :) http://nocircleno.com/blog/svg-and-handlebars-js-templates/  Also your question is very vague, you have not described what problems you are having and what solutions you have tried.

Comment: Please clarify your question. Where in the template do you want the chart? (Charts?) Does the template get re-rendered? Does the chart(s) data change? Why can't you just render your template, then `d3.select('#templateResult')` instead of `"body"`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If there should be only one instance of the graph inside the template, then all you need to do is tell d3 to append the svg element inside the `<script id="datatemplate">` tag instead of the body.

```
var svg = d3.select("#datatemplate").append("svg").attr("width",w).attr("height",h);
```

If, on the other hand, you would like your template to generate a d3 graph each time it is called, I don't think this is the proper way of doing things. Since d3 binds data to DOM elements and Handlebars generates HTML strings from data structures.

You could wrap your graph code inside a closure to which you pass your data and element you wish to bind to and then generate a new instance of the graph from a Handlebars helper:

```
function graphic( dataset, element ) {
  var w = 154;
  var h = 42;
  var rect_1_h = 5;
  var rect_2_h = rect_1_h * 2;
  var rect_2_w = rect_1_h/2;
  var rect_1_color = "#A1C9D9";
  var rect_2_color = "#999999";
  var text_color = "#555555";
  var font_size = 18;
  var font_family = "Segoe UI";

  /*------controller----*/

  var xScale = d3.scale.linear().domain([dataset[0],dataset[2]])
        .range([0,w]);

  var svg = d3.select( element ).append("svg").attr("width",w).attr("height",h);
  var rect1 = svg.append("rect").attr("x",0).attr("y",3*h/4).attr("width",w).attr("height",rect_1_h)
        .style("fill",rect_1_color);
  var rect2 = svg.append("rect").attr("x",xScale(dataset[1])).attr("y",3*h/4-rect_1_h/2).attr("width",rect_2_w)
        .attr("height",rect_2_h).style("fill",rect_2_color);

  //var texts = svg.selectAll("text").data(dataset).enter().append("text").text(function(d){ return d; }).attr("fill","red").attr("x",function(d,i){ return i*50  }).attr("y",30)

  var text1 = svg.append("text").attr("x",2).attr("y",h/3+2).text(dataset[0]).style("fill",text_color)
        .attr("font-size",font_size).attr("font-family",font_family);
  var text2 = svg.append("text").attr("x",w-42).attr("y",h/3+2).text(dataset[2]).style("fill",text_color)
        .attr("font-size",font_size).attr("font-family",font_family);

  return svg;
};

Handlebars.registerHelper('graphics', function( dataset, id ) {
  graphic( dataset, '#' + id );
});
```

And then in your template:

```
<script id="datatemplate" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
  {{#each objects}}
  <tr>
  <td>{{lp}}<span class="text1">{{lp2}}</span></td>
  <td>{{dc}}<span class="text1">{{dc2}}</span></td>
  <td>{{lp}}<span class="text1">{{lp2}}</span></td>
  </tr>
  {{/each}}
  <div id={{ id }}></div>
  {{graphics dataset id}} 
</script>
```